# Opencart Limiting drop down menu to show 5 cateogires

Tags: php, opencart

I have categories listed on the top navigation bar. Some have quite a few subcategories->products associated with them. So when a person goes over the navigation bar, some of the dropdown menus will span all the way down to the bottom of the screen. Is there a way to limit the amount shown to say around 5?
Would I need to go into the controller and limit something?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to change the default files of  OpenCart as if you upgrade then all changes will be lost.
I have seen one solution to achieve your requirement by changing the header.tpl. Open catalog/view/theme/YOUR_THEME/template/common/header.tpl
Find following lines of code:

```
<?php foreach (array_chunk($category['children'], ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column'])) as $children) { ?>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <?php foreach ($children as $child) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
          <?php } ?>
```

And replace with following lines of code:

```
 <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $key=>$child) { ?>
            <?php if($key<5){ ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
```

With this change there will be only one column.

For many sub-categories you can make multiple column of sub-categories in OpenCart.
While inserting category, in the data tab, insert "Columns" value to show multiple columns. You can see examples of "MP3 Players" category and its sub-categories in default installation.

Demo at:
https://webocreation.com/blog/limit-number-of-sub-categories-to-show-at-opencart-2